# How to not get pixel/serrated edges for a logo exported from Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, png, pixel

I created my logo with Inkscape so it's format SVG, on Inkscape when I zoom in it does not pixel.
[image]

But when I zoom in on the png file exported, the edges/strokes are not smooth, are serrated, pixel...
[image]

I think I understood that with png we will always have edges like this when zooming in. 
But how to save it otherwise to be able to have a final vector image without having to open it in Inkscape ? like if we want to send a final vector image to a printing company to print a logo for example

Thank you for any of your help

Thank you guys :D                                                                                                                         So PDF is the only way, at least there is that.

Wolff when I save as--- PDF--- a window pops up: 
- Restrict to PDF version: PDF1.5 or PDF1.4  => I choose 1.5 ?                                              - Text output options: Embed fonts => tick ? 
- Rasterize filter effects => untick ?
- Resolution for rasterization (dpi) => doesn't matter if rasterize is unticked right ?                                                                                               - Output page size: use document's page size or use exported object's size => object's size ?

But then the background is white and not transparent ... how is it going to be if printed out on a support (like for signage) ?

Comment: "Zooming in" on **any** raster format is going to make pixels at edges more visible. It's simply how raster images work. Raster images are not meant to be "zoomed".

Comment: PNG is a raster format. Raster images are made of pixels. If you zoom in on an image made of pixels, then you will see pixels.  If you save your image as SVG instead, and then view it in a browser, you will be able to zoom in without pixelization. SVGs are not made of pixels.  SVG means "Scalable Vector Graphic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*SVG* is a vector format used for vector graphics displayed on the web. SVG is the native format of Inkscape.

*PNG* is a raster (pixel) format used for images which are to be displayed on a screen.

The preferred format for printing purposes is *PDF*.

A PDF can both contain vector graphics and raster images.

Use `File > Save As...` and set `Save as type` to `Portable Document Format (*.pdf)`.